# Return List of User Ids from Active Directory

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, active-directory

Creating a method called `GetAdUsers`, which should return a set of information about each user in Active Directory (including the user id).

I am successfully returning the users `Email`, `UserName`, and `DisplayName`, but cannot get the **user's Ids**.

> How can I get the user Ids from Active Directory.

**My User Model**

```
public class Users
{
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string DisplayName { get; set; }
    public bool IsMapped { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }
}
```

**My Method to get Active Directory Info**

```
public List<Users> GetAdUsers()
{
    try
    {
        List<Users> lstADUsers = new List<Users>();
        string DomainPath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["...ldapPathHere..."];

        // Encapsulating an object in Active Directory Domain Service - the DirectoryEntry is initializing a new instance of AD Domain Services
        DirectoryEntry searchRoot = new DirectoryEntry(DomainPath);

        // Searching for all users in the domain
        DirectorySearcher search = new DirectorySearcher(searchRoot);

        // Filtering my results
        search.Filter = "(&(objectClass=user)(objectCategory=person))"; 
        search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("samaccountname");
        search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("mail");
        search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("usergroup");
        search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("displayname");//first name
        search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("userid");

        SearchResult result;
        SearchResultCollection resultCol = search.FindAll();

        if (resultCol != null)
        {
            for (int counter = 0; counter < resultCol.Count; counter++)
            {
                string UserNameEmailString = string.Empty;
                result = resultCol[counter];
                if (result.Properties.Contains("samaccountname") &&
                    result.Properties.Contains("mail") &&
                    result.Properties.Contains("displayname") &&
                    result.Properties.Contains("userid"))
                {
                    Users objSurveyUsers = new Users();
                    objSurveyUsers.Email = (String)result.Properties["mail"][0] +
                      "^" + (String)result.Properties["displayname"][0];
                    objSurveyUsers.UserName = (String)result.Properties["samaccountname"][0];
                    objSurveyUsers.DisplayName = (String)result.Properties["displayname"][0];
                    objSurveyUsers.UserId = (int) result.Properties["userid"][0];
                    lstADUsers.Add(objSurveyUsers);
                }
            }
        }
        return lstADUsers;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw;
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no attribute called `userId` in the base AD schema. What specifically are you trying to retrieve?

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean the Security Identifier or SID. This is held in the `objectSID` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean the samAccount or samAccountName ?(I'm not sure which one is the right one)

Edit:

Sorry, next time I should read the code completely - isn't a LDAP Query Case sensitive?